# When does $sce.getTrustedHtml(value) return true/false?

Tags: angularjs

I am having hard time understanding when does $sce.getTrustedHtml(value) return true or false. The documentation does not provide the information. I'd greatly appreciate if you could elaborate on cases when it returns true and when it does return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, the return value of `$sce.getTrustedHtml(value)` is:

> The return value of `$sce.getTrusted($sce.HTML, value)`

Basically `$sce.getTrustedHtml(value)` is just an alias for `$sce.getTrusted($sce.HTML, value)`. The return value of `$sce.getTrusted(context, value)` is:

> A version of the value that's safe to use in the given context, or throws an exception if this is impossible.

So according to the documentation, it never returns true or false (unless for some reason a boolean is the "safe" version of the value passed in).

Looking at the actual code, it looks like `$sce.getTrusted($sce.HTML, value)` basically just delegates to `$sanitize(value)`, whose documentation states that it returns "sanitized HTML" as a string. Again, no booleans. In fact, just glancing at the code that `$santize()` implements, these lines seem to preclude any possibility of a boolean return value:

```js
var buf = [];
htmlParser(html, htmlSanitizeWriter(buf, function(uri, isImage) {
   return !/^unsafe:/.test($$sanitizeUri(uri, isImage));
}));
return buf.join(''); //This can't return anything except a string
```

So it doesn't seem to be possible to get a boolean out of this.